# Wrong SHA1 from PHP & CF according to Amazon S3

Tags: php, coldfusion, amazon-s3, hmacsha1

Amazon consistently generates a different hash than PHP or CF, which causes a persistent "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error.

According [to the docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html), GET requests [without REST headers] are signed as follows:

```
Signature = URL-Encode( Base64( HMAC-SHA1( SecretAccessKey, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) ) );

StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    Expires + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
    CanonicalizedResource;
```

The example data:

- SecretAccessKey: **wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY**
- Content-MD5 and Content-Type: (optional - skipped)
- CanonicalizedAmzHeaders: (no headers - skipped)
- Resource: johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/puppy.jpg
- CanonicalizedResource: **/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg**

Two examples are provided:

1. Expires **1175139620**; Signature: **rucSbH0yNEcP9oM2XNlouVI3BH4%3D**
2. Expires **1141889120**; Signature: **vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D**

To recreate this (CFHMAC from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061270/87520)):

```
// PHP
$expires = 1175139620;
$SecretAccessKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
$StringToSign = "GET\n\n\n$expires\n/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg";
$signature = urlencode( base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha1',  utf8_encode($StringToSign), $SecretAccessKey, true)));

// ColdFusion
<cfset LF = chr(10)>
<cfset expires = 1141889120>
<cfset SecretAccessKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY">
<cfset StringToSign = "GET#LF##LF##LF##expires##LF#/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg">
<cfset signature = URLEncodedFormat( CFHMAC(StringToSign, SecretAccessKey))>
```

EXCEPT that $signature as returned by both languages is:

1. Expires **1175139620**; Signature: **NpgCjnDzrM%2BWFzoENXmpNDUsSn8%3D**
2. Expires **1141889120**; Signature: **fScKGHCDI0NY5E7CYp9Vc8VKMbY%3D**

We have been careful of these gotchas that others have mentioned:

1. hash_mac has a third argument, raw, which must be set to true.
2. The order of the stringToSign and key in the S3 psuedocode should be reversed.
3. The entire stringToSign must be on one line (so as not to create extra newline characters).

EDIT: Updated the newlines in the CF code based on Leigh's answer; now the CF matches the PHP.

I am obviously doing something wrong, but can't figure out what.
[I have heard it quipped that Amazon S3 would have been called CSS - "complicated storage service", but the name was already taken!]

Help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(May as well post this since I had already written it up .. :)

Two problems I can see

1. The date needs to be formatted a specific way
2. You need to use a `LF` rather than a literal "\n"

The result below matches that in [Authentication Examples](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationExamples) ie  `bWq2s1WEIj+Ydj0vQ697zp+IXMU=`. Note: I used [the hmacSHA1 function from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960258/104223), but changed it use `getBytes("UTF-8)`

**Code:**

```
    <cfset newLine = chr(10)>
    <cfset secretAccessKey = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY">
    <cfset stringToSign = "GET#newLine##newLine##newLine#Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000#newLine#/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg">
    <cfset signature = hmacSHA1(secretAccessKey, stringToSign)>
    <cfset finalSignature = URLEncodedFormat(binaryEncode(signature, "base64"))>
    <cfoutput>finalSignature = #finalSignature#</cfoutput>
```

****EDIT 1:**

Something is fishy. Most all of the examples on that page match up. But [REST Authentication Example 3: Query String Authentication Example here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html) shows a different key and string that produce the signature `vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D`. If you use those values in CF you *do* get the same signature. So I am wondering if it might just be a documentation error?

```
     <cfset secretAccessKey = "OtxrzxIsfpFjA7SwPzILwy8Bw21TLhquhboDYROV">
     <cfset stringToSign = "GET#newLine##newLine##newLine#1141889120#newLine#/quotes/nelson">
```

** **EDIT 2:**

I am pretty sure the REST examples are wrong. A search turned up [this link](http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch16s05.xhtml) containing yet another sample key. If you substitute that in the CF code, the signature is what you expected: `rucSbH0yNEcP9oM2XNlouVI3BH4%3D`.

```
    <cfset secretAccessKey = "uV3F3YluFJax1cknvbcGwgjvx4QpvB+leU8dUj2o">
    <cfset stringToSign = "GET#newLine##newLine##newLine#1175139620#newLine#/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg">
```

Comment: When using REST, the date is formatted as you say. When using just the GET, AWS needs a UTC timestamp. See later on in the same page. However, will try changing the newline and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, let me look at the examples further down.

Comment: Changing the LF gets the hash from CF to match the hash from PHP, but it does not match the hash from amazon. Thank you, already helpful.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect your answer thus far, but am still in desperate need of a way to get Amazon to recognize my requests.

Comment: Don't you hate it when you waste hours on a documentation error? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
<cffunction name="getRequestSignature" access="private" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="verb" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="bucket" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="objectKey" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="dateOrExpiration" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="contentType" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="contentMd5" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="canonicalizedAmzHeaders" type="string" default=""
        hint="A newline-delimited list of headers, in lexographical order, duplicates collapsed, and no extraneous whitespace.  See Amazon's description of 'CanonicalizedAmzHeaders' for specifics." />
    <cfscript>
        var stringToSign = "";
        var algo = "HmacSHA1";
        var signingKey = "";
        var mac = "";
        var signature = "";

        stringToSign = uCase(verb) & chr(10)
            & contentMd5 & chr(10)
            & contentType & chr(10)
            & dateOrExpiration & chr(10)
            & iif(len(canonicalizedAmzHeaders) GT 0, de(canonicalizedAmzHeaders & chr(10)), de(''))
            & "/" & listAppend(bucket, objectKey, "/");
        signingKey = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec").init(variables.awsSecret.getBytes(), algo);
        mac = createObject("java", "javax.crypto.Mac").getInstance(algo);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        signature = toBase64(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes()));

        return signature;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Completely stole it from here:
http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/projects/amazon-s3-cfc/

:)

Comment: The code I used was culled from the same source (referred to in the linked post), and doesn't work. Can you try it with Amazon's example and see if it works for you? For me it does not.